# How to start from storyboard and modal to MainWindow.xib?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard, xib

I have two projects, one starts from a storyboard and another is from  `MainWindow.xib`.

I want to combine them together, start from storyboard and click a button to launch the view of `MainWindow.xib`.

What do I have to set? How should I modify the code?

Please help, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Do you want open another app from current app?

Comment: No, I want combine them to one app . both use storyboard and xib .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should leave your project with storyboard as is, i.e. configure `Main Interface` combobox with that `storyboard` and set there `Initial View Controller`. At the some point, when you want to present view controller from `MainWindow.xib`, you could put some code like that:

```
MainWindow *mw = [[MainWindow alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainWindow" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:mw animated:YES completion:nil];
```